# Are there any keyboard hotkeys for any of the commands (clickable buttons) in the Build a Ship Screen?

Tags: master-of-orion-2

The Game is Master of Orion 2, any keyboard hotkeys that can be used to assist someone in designing the plans for a spaceship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there do not appear to be any keyboard shortcuts for designing ships. I found a PDF version of the [Master of Orion II manual](http://www.moo3.at/dl/file.php?id=30) online. In `Section 8: Ships` there is a sub section for `Designing Your Own` (*page 110 in the pdf*). This only describes how to use the interface using a mouse, with no mention of keyboard accelerator keys. In the actual game screen itself, you'll notice that there is no indication (tooltip or underlined char etc.) for a keyboard shortcut on any section.

Additionally, though I have played last a long time ago - I remember trying to use keys to navigate, and even that does not work (though it would be simpler than hotkeys for different sections). The game itself needs a mouse anyway, so I guess they did not see a need for alternate input methods in the design or construction screens.